# Does cf cli have some kind of max concurrent connection for a single user?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy apps using with cf cli commands with jenkins, and have some weird issue now.

It works fine with 1 or 2 concurrent deployments, but if there are more than 3-4 jobs running, any cf cli command returns strange errors randomly like;

> No space targeted, use 'cf target -s' to target a space.

or

> Server error, status code: 404, error code: 100004, message: The app
>   could not be found: 0da4xxxx-9476-473a-b77d-f02xxxxxx

However, there is no issue cf cli command itself if I run each cf command one by one.
(I'm only assigned to 1 org, 1 space, so no issue to choose space/target, and app is there if I do 'cf a' later.)

I fixed the config.json issue by this comment, but still blocked by strange behavior of cf cli. Any idea?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247160/5862540

Comment: How are you setting `CF_HOME` for each Jenkins job, and what are you setting it to? The cf CLI uses that location to store state between commands.

Comment: @ScottFrederick I'm using environmental variable of Jenkins in my script like; withEnv('CF_HOME'){ CF_HOME = "$WORKSPACE$BUILD_NUMBER" Then do something I need ....}. Then it will create different CF_HOME based on job and build number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cf CLI stores your configured API endpoint and access & refresh tokens in a local file, $CF_HOME/config.json.
Most cf CLI commands read this file when you invoke them, and many commands write to the file when they finish. Writing is performed for two reasons: when your access token expires, the cf CLI automatically requests a new token from UAA and updates the one in config.json. Also, we simply don't have any logic to check if any updates were made that need persisting, so the file gets written out again just in case.

So it's important to configure a different CF_HOME for any parallel executions of cf CLI commands to avoid random errors. And when your config.json is corrupted, just delete the file and configure your API endpoint & login again.

Comment: Hi, I think We (or someone else) already talked on slack. CF_HOME is different on each job, as a combination of  WORKSPACE and BUILD_NUMBER of jenkins. I'll cut down my script and see if I can make a sample script to reproduce and submit the issue.

Comment: Still unclear the cause, but I think there was some background job running to clean up workspaces and it might delete CF_HOME folder somehow. I rewrited the whole flow and it seems fine so far. Thanks.

Comment: @kevmando I am having a similar issue, what kind of background job are you talking about? Thank you.

Comment: @Yashu Not Jenkins default job, but my Jenkins server had a bunch of workspace cleaning jobs by IT team since it was a central server of our group. So the cf_home folders were deleted unexpected. If you have similar issue, then make sure cf_home folder is staying in the workspace until the job is done.